# Access value in first cell of HTMLTableRowElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is it possible to access the value in the first cell of a HTMLTableRowElement as defined at : http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLTableRowElement.html

Comment: anSelected[0].cells[0].innerText which works, I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: @user470184—innerText isn't supported by all browsers, you need `innerText || textContent`.

Comment: @RobG textContent is not an attribute of http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLTableCellElement.html ?

Comment: @user470184—[textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) is a DOM **property**, innerText was a proprietary MS invention that was "standardised" buy HTML5 and is supported by many browsers, but not all (as are many new features in HTML5). So you need to use feature detection to determine which to use, e.g. `var el = document.getElementById('foo'); return el.innerText || el.textContent;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If your row is in a variable called `tr`, just access `tr.cells[0]` and get whatever you want from it.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I'd like to answer with something more appropriate that I believe the OP was looking for, based on the response

```
anSelected[0].cells[0].innerText which works, I'm looking for alternatives
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement),

The `cells` property `(HTMLTableRowElement.cells)`

Returns a live HTMLCollection containing the cells in the row. The HTMLCollection is live and is automatically updated when cells are added or removed.

So we can now check MDN for [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), take a look at the `.item()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item), which is described to do exactly what you want:

The method takes an `index` parameter, which is the position of the Node to be returned.

So, to avoid the following:

`anSelected[0].cells[0].innerText`

You can use the the `.item()` method:

`anSelected.item(0).cells.item(0).innerText`

Comment: isn't `.item(n)` exactly the same as `[n]`?

Comment: Essentially, yes it is. It's more or less a different approach syntactically.